# Geofencing producing random notifications

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, uilocalnotification, geofencing

I am building an app that utilizes geofencing to fire a local notification. I have a view that allows the user to change the location and radius of geofence B. This geofence only fires when the homeNotification is set to true. homeNotification is only set to true when the user enters geofence A. This part is working correctly. My problem starts when the user changes the location of geofence B. The initial location of geofence B still fires a notification but does not vibrate or make a noise. It only displays the notification. The notification also fires on entry and exit even though I have set the notifyOnExit = false. The region is also not present in the CLMonitoredRegions when I print them to the console. The code is below.

```
for region in self.locationManager.monitoredRegions {
            if let circularRegion = region as? CLCircularRegion {
                if circularRegion.identifier == "Home" {
                    self.homeCoordinateOld = circularRegion.center
                    self.homeRadiusOld = circularRegion.radius
                    self.homeIdentifierOld = circularRegion.identifier
                }
            }
        }
        let regionOld = CLCircularRegion(center: self.homeCoordinateOld, radius: self.homeRadiusOld, identifier: self.homeIdentifierOld)
        print("\(regionOld)")
        self.locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(regionOld)
        let region = CLCircularRegion(center: homeCoordinate!, radius: 76, identifier: "Home")
        region.notifyOnEntry = true
        region.notifyOnExit = false
        self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
```

Here is the full code where I created geofence B. The same view controller is used to change the location.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    let home = view.annotation
    let homeCoordinate = home?.coordinate
    let homeLat = home?.coordinate.latitude
    let homeLon = home?.coordinate.longitude
    let homeAddress = searchedStoreNames["\(homeCoordinate!)"]
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm", message: "Would you like to add \(homeAddress!) as your home location?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: handleCancel))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add Home", style: .Default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in

        if !CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLCircularRegion) {
            showSimpleAlertWithTitle("Error", message: "Geofencing is not supported on this device!", viewController: self)
            return
        }
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .AuthorizedAlways {
            showSimpleAlertWithTitle("Warning", message: "Your geotification is saved but will only be activated once you grant permission to access the device location. Do this under settings.", viewController: self)
        }

        for region in self.locationManager.monitoredRegions {
            if let circularRegion = region as? CLCircularRegion {
                if circularRegion.identifier == "Home" {
                    self.homeCoordinateOld = circularRegion.center
                    self.homeRadiusOld = circularRegion.radius
                    self.homeIdentifierOld = circularRegion.identifier
                }
            }
        }
        let regionOld = CLCircularRegion(center: self.homeCoordinateOld, radius: self.homeRadiusOld, identifier: self.homeIdentifierOld)
        print("\(regionOld)")
        self.locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(regionOld)
        let region = CLCircularRegion(center: homeCoordinate!, radius: 76, identifier: "Home")
        region.notifyOnEntry = true
        region.notifyOnExit = false
        self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)


        homeLocation["coordinates"] = "\(home!.coordinate)"
        homeLocation["address"] = "\(homeAddress!)"
        homeLocation["latitude"] = "\(homeLat!)"
        homeLocation["longitude"] = "\(homeLon!)"
        //savedStores.append(["name":"Home", "coordinates": "\(home!.coordinate)", "address": "\(homeAddress!)", "identifier": "\(identifier)"])

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(homeLocation, forKey: "homeLocation")
        homeNotifications = true
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "homeNotifications")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.searchText.text = ""
        self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapAnnotations)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        print("Monitored Regions \(self.locationManager.monitoredRegions)")

    }))
    presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is geofence A

```
@IBAction func saveTabbed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm", message: "Would you like to add \(storeNameHolder) to favorites? This will create a reminder.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: handleCancel))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add Store", style: .Default, handler: {(UIAlertAction) in

        if !CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLCircularRegion) {
            showSimpleAlertWithTitle("Error", message: "Geofencing is not supported on this device!", viewController: self)
            return
        }
          if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .AuthorizedAlways {
        showSimpleAlertWithTitle("Warning", message: "Your geotification is saved but will only be activated once you grant Bag-It! permission to access the device location. Do this under settings.", viewController: self)
        } 

        #if FREE

            if savedStores.count == 5 {
                showSimpleAlertWithTitle("Favorites Filled", message: "You can only have 3 favorite stores in Bag-It! Free. To save more stores, download Bag-It! from the App Store.", viewController: self)
                return
            }
        #else
            if savedStores.count == 19 {
                showSimpleAlertWithTitle("Favorites Filled", message: "You can only have 19 favorite stores at one time.", viewController: self)
                return
            }
        #endif
        let newRadiusInMeters = Double(self.newRadius) / 3.2808
        let region = CLCircularRegion(center: self.storeCoordinates, radius: newRadiusInMeters, identifier: "\(self.storeIdentifierHolder)")
        print("\(region)")
        region.notifyOnEntry = true
        region.notifyOnExit = false
        self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
        savedStores.append(["name":self.storeNameHolder, "coordinates": "\(self.storeLat), \(self.storeLon)", "address": "\(self.storeAddressHolder)", "identifier": "\(self.storeIdentifierHolder)", "longitude": "\(self.storeLon)", "latitude": "\(self.storeLat)"])

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(savedStores, forKey: "savedStores")
        storeNotifications = true
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "storeNotifications")
        print("\(self.locationManager.monitoredRegions)")
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }))
    presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Where is your geofence B?And what you did to make it active.

Comment: @Lumialxk I have added the code to show how I mad geofence B active.

Comment: I can only find you created only one region notification named "Home".Is it right?What you did to create B is important.

Comment: @Lumialxk Geofence B is known as "Home" Geofence A's code has been posted. Geofence A is known as a "Store"